# Is it possible to have Codelens in Razor Pages?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codelens

I would like to view "Git changes", "authors" and "work items" through codelens in .cshtml files. Any way to enable them? Settings didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible at the moment, however there is an [tracked issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1758) for it so it might be implemented in the future.